# Is it possible to apply L'Hospital to $ \lim_{x \to\infty}(e^{-x^2}+\frac{2}{x} )\sin^2(\frac{2}{x^4})x^8\cos(\frac{3}{x^8}))) $?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a question about how to calculate this limit; can I apply L'Hospital?

$$
\lim_{x \to\infty}(e^{-x^2}+\frac{2}{x} )\sin^2(\frac{2}{x^4})x^8\cos(\frac{3}{x^8})))
$$

Is it possible to make a change of variable such as $$ t^2 = \frac{1}{x^4}\;?$$

Comment: Suppose you make that substitution.  What do you get?  Show it in your post

Comment: I'm confused. Do you think this can only be solved using L'Hospital's rule or would you really like to do it some other way?

Comment: Note that cos factor at end tends to 1. And the $x^8\sin$ stuff tends to $4$ so we are left with $4(e^{-x^2}+2/x)$ and then the desired limit is...

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is $|\sin x |\leq |x|$. Therefore, $\sin^2\left(\frac{2}{x^4}\right)\leq \frac{4}{x^8}$. It should be clear from here how to use Squeeze Theorem. L'Hospitals was undoubtedly not the intent of the problem.

Comment: thanks, i try to squeeze theorem

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to\infty}(e^{-x^2}+\frac{2}{x} )\sin^2(\frac{2}{x^4})x^8\cos(\frac{3}{x^8})))$$

$$    \lim_{x \to\infty}(e^{-x^2}+\frac{2}{x} )
   = \lim_{x \to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{e^{x^2}}+\dfrac{2}{x} \right)
   = 0$$

$$   \lim_{x \to\infty}\sin^2\left(\frac{2}{x^4}\right)x^8
   = \left[ 2\lim_{x \to\infty}
           \dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{2}{x^4}\right)}{\frac{2}{x^4}}\right]^2
   = 4$$

$$   
      \lim_{x \to\infty} \cos \left(\frac{3}{x^8}\right) = 1
$$

Comment: I haven't thought about it